# Define popover template inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-bootstrap, angular-template

Im trying to create a directive with popover functionality.
My template isnt the shortest one, so I decided to use `templateUrl` for that. 
and then, I decided to use a template for my popover, so I tried using `ng-template` definition inside my directive template file, and using it with `popover-template`, but I cant see the tooltip.
Here's the example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
    {{label}}
</script>

<div ng-if='label.length >= 5' popover-template='myTemplate.html' popover-trigger='mouseenter'>
    {{label | limitTo: 5}}{{label.length >= limit ? '..' : ''}}
</div>
<div ng-if='label.length < 5'>
    {{label}}
</div>
```

Why cant it be done?
My main reason of doing it is because I want to keep it clean & elegant (of course) and I want to apply some styling on my popover.

Update: I added the directive, though Its working and just to complete the picture.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                label: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'my-directive.html'
        };
    });
```

Comment: Where is the directive? It's not clear your code.

Comment: ui.bootstrap module was not initialized angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: @BalajiM It is, Its a lot of content to put here, so I couldnt write everything here. I put here the important stuff

Comment: @e-r-a-n try this http://plnkr.co/edit/TTdWNM?p=preview

Comment: @BalajiM Thanks, but in this form of use I can get templates to work, but in my example The template is used inside of the directive's templateUrl. and in this usage it doesnt work.

Comment: @e-r-a-n change that template url to myTemplate.html, check this http://plnkr.co/edit/AdKZdXLaXpxwHCVXT0oq?p=preview